# java version issue :(

Tags: windows, java, aix

My application is running in AIX System with the versions given below.

I'm working in my windows des

```
Host Operating System is AIX, version 5.3

Java version = J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc-32 j9vmap3223-20080315 (JIT enabled)

J9VM - 20080314_17962_bHdSMr

JIT  - 20080130_0718ifx2_r8

GC   - 200802_08, Java Compiler = j9jit23, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM

was.install.root = /hosting/products/WebSphereT03

user.install.root = /hosting/configs/WebSphereT03/AppServer

Java Home = /hosting/products/WebSphereT03/java/jre

ws.ext.dirs = /hosting/products/WebSphereT03/java/lib:/hosting/configs/WebSphereT03/AppServer/classes:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/classes:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/lib:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/installedChannels:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/lib/ext:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/web/help:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime

Classpath = /hosting/configs/WebSphereT03/AppServer/properties:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/properties:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/lib/startup.jar:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/lib/bootstrap.jar:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/lib/j2ee.jar:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/lib/lmproxy.jar:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/lib/urlprotocols.jar:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/java/lib/tools.jar:/hosting/apps/T03-logProcessor-sit/lib:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/bin:/usr/mqm/java/lib

Java Library path = /hosting/products/WebSphereT03/java/jre/bin:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/java/jre/bin:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/java/jre/bin/classic:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/java/jre/bin:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/bin:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/java/jre/bin/j9vm:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/java/jre/bin/j9vm:/hosting/products/WebSphereT03/java/jre/bin/j9vm:/usr/lib:/usr/mqm/java/lib
```

Comment: What exactly is the question ?

Comment: What is your question? What does it have to do with programming?

Comment: What makes you suspect a version issue? What are the symptoms? This question is terribly stated/formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this one:

```
Java version = J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc-32 j9vmap3223-20080315 (JIT enabled)
```

Your RAD version should match the WAS version running on your server.  You should be using the certified JVM in the correct version of RAD.

Comment: Should be part of your RAD.  You only have one source - IBM.